# ¿Cómo evitar que se reste la hora de comida cuando es sábado en un sistema de puntualidad y asistencia en PHP y MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy desarrollando un sistema de puntualidad y asistencia pero tengo un pequeño bug que no puedo arreglar.

Estoy sacando el total de horas trabajadas dentro de un rango de dos fechas ingresadas por dos input de tipo date.

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando sea de Lunes a Viernes se reste 1 hora de comida, y cuando sea sábado NO se reste la hora de comida.

Aquí ingreso el rango de fechas de los resultados que quiero filtrar, por ejemplo aquí filtro del 4 de Marzo al 6 de Marzo. Ese rango incluye Jueves, Viernes y Sábado.
[image]

Estos son los resultados que me arroja. Si hacemos el cálculo de la columna "Horas trabajadas" nos debería dar aproximadamente 15 horas con 4 minutos.
[image]

Y aquí vemos que el resultado nos da 14 horas con 4 minutos, ya que está restando la hora de comida del Sábado y no debería.
[image]

Esta es mi consulta de MySQL en PHP :

```
    `$horasTrabajadas = SELECT if(dia != 'Sabado', SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(DATE_SUB(timediff(entrada, salida), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)))), SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(entrada, salida))))) as horas_trabajadas
    FROM ivms_info 
    WHERE dia <> 'Domingo'
    AND entrada != 0 AND salida != 0 
    AND TIMEDIFF(entrada, salida) > 0 
    AND idUser = '$id'
    AND fecha BETWEEN CAST('$de' AS DATE) AND CAST('$hasta' AS DATE);

$query = mysqli_query($connectionString, $horasTrabajadas);
$result = mysqli_fetch_row($query);`
```

En mi HTML recupero el valor que me da la consulta:

```
`<h6 class="mt-3">HORAS TRABAJADAS</h6>
 <h2>
                <?php if (is_null($result[0]) == true) {
                  $result[0] = "00:00:00";
                  echo $result[0];
                } else {
                  echo $result[0];
                } ?>
 </h2>`
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para ganar tu primera medalla. Creo que a la pregunta le vendría bien que incluyas unas cuantas filas de ejemplo y el resultado que esperas obtener con esas filas.

Comment: @jachguate ya lo edité, espero sea más entendible. Gracias por tu retro.

Comment: La consulta ejecutada en MySQL te devuelve bien los datos?

Comment: @Jakala sí amigo, sólo que al resultado le está restando la hora de comida de los días sábados, y eso es lo que no quiero.

Comment: nos vendria bien ver los datos para poder ayudarte.. asi sobre el aire es muy dificil

Comment: @gbianchi ya añadí imágenes, ojalá y sea de su ayuda.

Comment: los datos tenemos que ver... no las imagenes de las app...

Comment: Si tienes una columna fecha puedes filtrar usando [`DAYNAME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) por ejemplo: `WHERE DAYNAME(columnaFecha) <> 'Saturday'` De todos modos falta contexto para poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concentrándonos exclusivamente en recuperar los datos, vía SQL, veo que buscas obtener ya el resumen de las horas, sin embargo tu consulta actual hace el `sum()` donde no esperaría verlo (y no me explico como mySQL puede aceptar esa consulta, pero eso ya son otros 10 centavos).

Voy a llevarte pasito a paso, espero que ir en este orden te ayude a visualizar dónde está actualmente tu error y, más importante, el proceso lógico que generalmente se sigue para llegar a una consulta consistente y funcional.

- primero necesitamos obtener el tiempo de cada día, de manera que podamos sumarlo. Me parece genial obtenerlo en segundos, que son fáciles de sumar, así que, lo básico, es lo que ya haces, para cada día:

  ```
    select TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(entrada, salida))
  ```

  Esto nos va a dar el número de segundos entre la hora de entrada y la hora de salida de cada día.
- Ahora pensemos en obtener el tiempo del almuerzo. Ya que estamos trabajando en segundos obtengamoslo de una vez en segundos. La idea es que, cuándo es sábado debemos obtener 0 segundos, y para los otros días debemos obtener 3600 segundos, que es el equivalente a una hora. Para obtener ese valor, podemos valernos de una sentencia `case`, por ejemplo esta:

  ```
    select case 
             when dia = 'Sábado' then 0
             else 3600
           end
  ```
- Ahora, en cada día, lo que en realidad necesitamos es la resta de ambos valores, por ejemplo:

  ```
    select TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(entrada, salida)) - case when dia = 'Sábado' then 0 else 3600 end
  ```
- Luego, en realidad, no queremos los valores individuales, sino necesitamos sumar los valores de todos los días para obtener el total

  ```
    select sum(select TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(entrada, salida)) - case when dia = 'Sábado' then 0 else 3600 end)
  ```
- Finalmente, ese número total de segundos, queremos convertirlo de nuevo a horas, para lo cual nos valemos de la función `sec_to_time`, como ya sabías:

  ```
    select sec_to_time(sum(select TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(entrada, salida)) - case when dia = 'Sábado' then 0 else 3600 end))
  ```

Poniendo todo en la sentencia, quedaría algo como:

```
SELECT sec_to_time(sum(select TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(entrada, salida)) - case when dia = 'Sábado' then 0 else 3600 end)) as horas_trabajadas
  FROM ivms_info 
 WHERE dia <> 'Domingo'
   AND entrada != 0 AND salida != 0 
   AND TIMEDIFF(entrada, salida) > 0 
   AND idUser = '$id'
   AND fecha BETWEEN CAST('$de' AS DATE) AND CAST('$hasta' AS DATE);
```

**OJO** que he hecho la comparación con la cadena `'Sábado'` (con tilde), que es el nombre del día en español. Tu la tenías con `'Sabado'` (sin tilde), que no existe. Si tu sistema tuviese `'Sabado'` en lugar de `'Sábado'`, mi sugerencia es corregirlo ahora mismo... si por alguna razón no se puede, entonces, ni modo, comparalo con la cadena sin tilde.

Comment: La sentencia ha funcionado!! Agradezco tu tiempo para resolver mi problema. @jachguate Me has salvado.